# DHCP Server stopped responding after switching TB to Ethernet Adapter

Tags: macos, network, server.app

OS: 10.10.2 w/ Server.app

I had created a LAG (link aggregate group) on my Mac Mini server. Since then DHCP services stopped working. This is my current bootpd.plist file. The LAG is called bond0 according to my Mac.

Any ideas what I can do to resolve the DHCP issue? None of the clients can obtain an address. Does DHCP not support bonded interfaces?

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Subnets</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>allocate</key>
                        <true/>
                        <key>dhcp_domain_name</key>
                        <string>example.com</string>
                        <key>dhcp_domain_name_server</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>10.0.0.11</string>
                                <string>10.0.0.12</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>dhcp_domain_search</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>example.com</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>dhcp_router</key>
                        <string>10.0.0.1</string>
                        <key>lease_max</key>
                        <integer>604800</integer>
                        <key>name</key>
                        <string>10.0.0.0/24 Network</string>
                        <key>net_address</key>
                        <string>10.0.0.0</string>
                        <key>net_mask</key>
                        <string>255.255.255.0</string>
                        <key>net_range</key>
                        <array>
                                <string>10.0.0.150</string>
                                <string>10.0.0.174</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>selected_port_name</key>
                        <string>bond0</string>
                        <key>uuid</key>
                        <string>0135C3AF-5933-4316-9FD3-ECE1B2F1A57B</string>
                </dict>
        </array>
        <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
        <array>
                <string>bond0</string>
        </array>
        <key>timeServiceStarted</key>
        <string>2015-03-30 20:03:31 +0000</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: did you try some packet capture to see if incoming DHCP requests arrive well, and where the answers (if any) go?

Comment: Is there a utility I can use on Mac to do this?

Comment: from a terminal you can use `tcpdump`, but this is not very intuitive, or you can install Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/ -- site currently down, but I guess it will be back soon)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your DHCP Server uses the wrong network interface to propagate the leases after building the bond:

- Open Server.app and connect to your server
- Click in the left pane on Advanced -> DHCP
- Open the DHCP network in question by double-clicking on it or highlight it and click on the pencil at the bottom
- Check the 'Network Interface'. Probably you still have an old network interface (Presumably Ethernet 0 or 1) chosen there. Change it to Bond0 (or whatever the human readable name is)
- Hit the OK button and quit Server.app

Comment: This was the first thing I checked. Even my bootpd.plist shows the values have changed from e0 or e1.

Comment: @mavxx84 Oh sorry yeah you are right. I  skipped that part obviously :-(

Comment: @mavxx84 Did you already flush the arp caches of the clients (`sudo arp -a -d`)? Please add `ifconfig -a` executed on the server. Does the switch support LACP?

Comment: I did flush arp caches on clients. Still not working. It seems DHCP service does not respond on bond0

Comment: @mavxx84 I tested your scenario in a virtual environment yesterday (without a switch of course) before posting my answer and it worked trouble-free

Comment: I'm using the Ubiquiti Unifi US-48-500W switch. I have ports 17 and 18 bonded on the switch as well.

Comment: If I remove the aggregate port, then the status of my two adapters show Fail in OS X - Networking. Both are showing OK with the settings correct on my switch.